# How can I include a cell reference in a searchFolders function?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to search for folders that contain a text string which is located in a specific cell in my spreadsheet, and then return the folder ID. This code works fine other than my folderID line.

Here is the code:
`

```
function getFilesAndFolders() {
  var folderName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var folderID = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains"+folderName).next().getId();
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFilesByName("app.csv");
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheetName = writeDataToSheet(contents);
  var home = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Manage");
  home.activate();
}
```

`

I've tried a few variations of the searchFolders query but it keeps returning errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of the search query of `DriveApp.searchFolders`, please enclose the search value of `contains` by the single quotes and/or the double quotes.
- In your script, `DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains"+folderName).next()` is the Class Folder object.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getFilesAndFolders() {
  var folderName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var folder = DriveApp.searchFolders("title contains '" + folderName + "'"); // or var folder = DriveApp.searchFolders(`title contains '${folderName}'`);
  if (folder.hasNext()) {
    var file = folder.next().getFilesByName("app.csv");
    var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString());
    var sheetName = writeDataToSheet(contents);
    var home = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Manage");
    home.activate();
  }
}
```

- In your script, it seems that `sheetName` is not used.

#### Reference:

- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-search-terms)

Comment: Thank you, that worked! And you're right, I was able to remove that 'var' and just have it run that function, which is created in a lower line.

Comment: @DataApprentice98 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.